# Rails customizing bootstrap variables with scss doesn't work when assets are precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Everything looked beautiful until I deployed to Heroku, assets got precompiled, and now the ui is a horrible mess.

In my application.css I have:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

In my app.css.scss I have:

```
$gridColumns: 14;
$gridColumnWidth: 70px;
.. etc ..

@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

Why do the variable changes work in development but not in production? Debugging with firebug shows that the widths are based on the old grid system.

How can I get the values to be overwritten with precompiled assets?

Comment: You should really look into precompiling your assets locally instead of letting Heroku do it.

Comment: I'm starting to realize that.. I asked 2 other questions already tonight regarding getting a production environment working locally to test it out :(

Comment: Ahhhh it worked! #blinddeploy

Comment: Tell us what you have done to get it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply ran

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and then committed to version control, deployed again, and it worked. Doesn't make sense, but I guess precompiling them yourself is different than what Heroku does.